# Using spread operator to update an object value

Tags: javascript, spread-syntax

I have a function that adds a key to incoming object, but I have been told to use the spread operator for that, I have been told that I can use the spread operator to create a new object with the same properties and then set isAvailable on it.

```
  return new Partner(ServerConfig, capabilities, initialState)
}

class Partner {
  constructor (ServerConfig, capabilities, initialState) {
    initialState.isAvailable = true
```

So I tried something like this but couldn't succeed, can you help me? and confused, should I use the spread operator in this way, return from a function ?

```
newObject = {}

// use this inside a function and get value from return

       return {
         value: {
           ...newObject,
           ...initialState
         }
       }

initialState.isAvailable = true
```

Comment: `...` isn't an operator. It's syntax, notation, but not an operator (like the `()` in a `for` statement).

Answer (score 195, accepted):

The properties are added *in order*, so if you want to override existing properties, you need to put them at the end instead of at the beginning:

```
return {
  value: {
    ...initialState,
    ...newObject
  }
}
```

You don't need `newObject` (unless you already have it lying around), though:

```
return {
  value: {
    ...initialState,
    isAvailable: newValue
  }
}
```

Example:

```js
const o1 = {a: "original a", b: "original b"};
// Doesn't work:
const o2 = {a: "updated a", ...o1};
console.log(o2);
// Works:
const o3 = {...o1, a: "updated a"};
console.log(o3);
```

Answer (score 49):

If you know the name of the property (`a` in the example below), then @crowder's answer is perfect:

```
const o3 = {...o1, a: "updated a"};
console.log(o3);
```

If the property name is in a variable, then you need to use [Computed Property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) syntax:

```
let variable = 'foo'
const o4 = {...o1, [variable]: "updated foo"};
console.log(o4);
```

Comment: so this not going to work  {l5, l10, l20, opponentFreq, currentSeasonFreq, ...play } ? play have l5,l10,l20...

Answer (score 0):

Spreading the object usint `...` will keep your state integrity. Let's say you have an initial state

```
 initialState={isOpen:false,count:0}
```

Assume that you want to add another property but you want to keep other properties:

```
return {  ...initialState,isAvailable:true
        }
```

this will lead to

```
 initialState={isOpen:false,count:0,isAvailable:true}
```

we just added a new property without discarding the other properties. maybe another part of your app is using other properties so we still keep them. let's say you want to update `isOpen` state. you spread the initial state first and then add the last piece of logic

```
 return {  ...initialState,isOpen:true
        }
```

this will lead to this

```
initialState={isOpen:true,count:0,isAvailable:true}
```

Now maybe on your current page, since `isOpen:true` you might be showing a different piece of UI to the user. Let's say you want to update the `count` this time. You could write this too

```
 return {  count:5 }
```

Now your current state has only `count:5` so you have lost other properties in your state. Now there is no `isOpen` property. If you did not handle the `isOpen` logic successfully while you were displaying a different UI, your app will crash. but if you handle correctly, `isOpen` would lead to `falsy` so your page will not show that piece of UI to the user.