# modifying an object using ... in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an object called `added` that looks like this:

```
{
  title: "test1",
  startDate: "Mon Apr 15 2019 10:30:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)",
  endDate: "Mon Apr 15 2019 11:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)",
  allDay: false
}
```

I was trying edit the `startDate` and `endDate` field of this object by doing:

```
added = {
  ...added,
  {added.startDate: "111", added.endDate: "222"}       
}
```

But this gives me an error that says

> unexpected token, expected ,

What is the right way of doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using spread operator to update an object value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49491393/using-spread-operator-to-update-an-object-value)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When reassigning `added` as a new object literal, everything inside the `{}`s needs to be key-value pairs, *or* it needs to spread (with `...`) an object with key-value pairs into the new object. You can't put a *plain object* into an object literal (unless you spread it), because an object is a value, not a key-value pair.

Change to:

```
added = {
  ...added,
  startDate: "111",
  endDate: "222"
}
```

You could also do

```
added = {
  ...added,
  ...{
    startDate: "111",
    endDate: "222"
  }
}
```

which would be valid syntax (but silly do to - easier to just list the new properties in the outer object literal).