# How to use Enum as a key type for passing properties in Vue?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

After finding [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44243060) to use an enum to define an object, I wanted to use such an object in Vue.

```
export enum Options {
  randSize = 'randomSized',
  timer = 'showTimer',
  randAngle = 'randomAngle',
  colours = 'multiColour',
  cardSize = 'cardSize',
  numCards = 'numCards'
}
```

(parent component):

```
import { Options} from './util'
let options : {[key in Options]: number | boolean} = {
  [Options.randSize]: true,
  [Options.timer] : false,
  [Options.randAngle] : true,
  [Options.colours] : true,
  [Options.cardSize] : 8,
  [Options.numCards] : 20
```

}

I have also (thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49491393)) a way to change option values:

```
function changeOption( option: string, value: number | boolean) {
  options = {...options,[option]:value}
}
```

but when I want to use these options as a component property, the enum is not recognised:

(parent template):

```
      <game-options 
        :options = "options"
        @done-setup = "gameStarted=true"
        @change-options="changeOption"
      >
      </game-options>
```

(child component):

```
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
import { Options} from '../util'

const props = defineProps<{
  options: {[key in Options]: number | boolean}
}>()

onMounted(() =>{
  console.log(props.options);
  let foo = props.options.randSize;
})
```

gives an error `Property 'randSize' does not exist on type '{ randomSized: number | boolean; showTimer: number | boolean; randomAngle: number | boolean; multiColour: number | boolean; cardSize: number | boolean; numCards: number | boolean; }'.ts(2339)`

How to correct this?

Comment: can you make sure your util path is correct?

Comment: "on type...." - you truncated the relevant part. defineProps is a macro and shouldn't be used with external types, afaik this prevents it from working normally.

Comment: @UsamaArslan yes, path is correct, e.g. I can do `let foo1 = Options.randSize` and it's happy with that.

Comment: @EstusFlask, OK, thanks.  I have added the full error now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [post you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66078799/48831959), it says

> `in Enum` compiles to enum *values* and `keyof typeof` to enum *keys*.

Looking at `randSize` in your enum

```
export enum Options {
  randSize = 'randomSized',
  ...
}
```

the key is `randSize` and the value is `randomSized`. So for `{[key in Options]: number | boolean}`, the prop will be called `randomSized`, not `randSize`.

---

When using more complex types, keep in mind that there are [some hard syntax limitation](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api#syntax-limitations), particularly, `defineProps` cannot do actual type analysis, it only resolves syntax. To me, it is not always clear where one ends and the other begins. In this case, `defineProps` cannot resolve the type, Vue will only know that there is an `options` prop, but it has no idea about its type. But since the IDE can do actual type completion, it will infer the whole type and give you type errors and auto completion (see [playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)). But Vue will not give you type errors. If this is acceptable, all is well.

Note however that this:

```
const props = defineProps<{
  [key in Options]: number | boolean
}>()
```

would **not** work at all, as Vue cannot resolve the actual shape of the type.

Comment: Thanks. Oddly, when I posted the question, `randomSized` etc were not offered by intellisense. After closing and and re-opening VS Code, they now are, so the solution is now much easier! I can now do things like `<v-switch v-model="props.options.randomSized"  @change="emit('changeOptions',Options.randSize,props.options.randomSized)" label="Random-sized"></v-switch>`